# Angular-UI One day is subtracted from date in ui-date

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs, angular-ui

**The situation**
I want to use ui-date to set/edit a date in my app. I use the latest stable versions of angular, angular-ui, jquery-ui etc.

**The problem**
As soon as a date is selected using the datepicker the date in my model will equal the selected date minus 1 day. It will also get send to my server and saved in my database this way.

**The plunker**
http://plnkr.co/edit/Ft14Wa?p=preview
Initially the date in the datepicker input and the date in my model are the same. After picking a date they differ.

**The question**
What is going (wr)on(g) here???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ui-date expects your model to be an actual date object. In your case it's a string. If you take a look at the console you'll see that angularUI actually informs you about that. Then it advises you to add additional ui-date-format tag with the specified date format with which your date string will be parsed into date object.

Long story short, your need to adjust your input as this:

```
<input ui-date="{dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'}" ui-date-format="yy-mm-dd" ng-model="customer.contract_end_date"></input>
```

[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FQR3Fg).

Comment: I did use the `ui-date-format` directive but without a value. Earlier I did not use the `"{dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'}"` so it didn't work, I lost track somewhere a long the way that I hadn't tried it this way. Thnx @stewie!

Comment: jQuery ui configuration options are a bit cryptic. I myself often get lost with them.

Answer (score 4):

this solves my problem.
angularjs uses default timezone which considers hour time. seting timezone option of ng-model to UTC clear hour times......

```
ng-model-options="{timezone:'UTC'}"
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that angular is using its default timezone when parsing the date selected on the datepicker. To resolve the issue you can use the ng-model-options directive which accepts a "timezone" parameter.

```
<input type="text" ng-model-options="{timezone:'UTC'}" ... >
```

Answer (score 0):

I set date format as dd-mm-yyyy as my requirement. then set date-type as string.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-9"
                        data-date-format="dd-MM-yyyy" data-autoclose="1"
                        ng-model="modelName"
                        date-type="string" bs-datepicker required>
```

Comment: support for date-type of string has been dropped in newer versions of AngularJS