# Why does angularjs bootstrap datepicker pick one day before?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using [angularjs bootstrap datepicker directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)
and when I set a date from model it picks a day before the selected date.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="dt = '2014-09-24'">2014-09-24</button>
```

Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/7lyf0I3I5HpCi4EpsjzD?p=preview) with the issue.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the way JS handles dates natively. AngularUI team mentions this in the docs.

Here's one solution: [Angular-UI One day is subtracted from date in ui-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226766/angular-ui-one-day-is-subtracted-from-date-in-ui-date)

Comment: This answer is about angular-ui but the question is about angular-bootstrap datepicker.

Comment: If you click on the link in the question, you can see that he's using the Angular UI Datepicker.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone needing a solution in the .NET Web Api world, this line worked well for me:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
```

It was due to the JsonFormatter spitting out the time in the wrong time zone.

Comment: Am using the Web API2 had the same problem on the Angular side of things, yours turned out to be just what the doctor order. Thanks

Comment: This is exactly I was looking for.

Comment: this is the best answer if ur using web api as backend amd thanks for sharing this @john lee

Answer (score 1):

my solution is to use a directive to fix the minus 1 issue, and also to format the view and model values:

```
app.directive('ngBootstrapFix',['$filter', function($filter) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    priority: 1,
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
        viewValue = $filter('date')(viewValue, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        return viewValue;
      });
      ngModelCtrl.$render = function() {
        var val = $filter('date')(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
        $element.val(val);
      };
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: this didnt work for me, I can see the filter being executed but no change on selecting the previous day.

Comment: Yup same here filter being executed but no change

Answer (score 0):

I just initialized the ngModel with new Date(), and the date was set correctly thereafter, even after I changed it with the date picker !