# AngularJS Calendar selects 1 day before selected date

Tags: angularjs, calendar

I am new to AngularJS and I have weird problem while using calendar in angular JS. Whenever I select any date in calendar it shows 1 day before. 
E.g. If I select : 3/2/2016 {M/D/Y) it selects 3/1/2016.

I have tried multiple solutions: 
[Why does angularjs bootstrap datepicker pick one day before?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611645/why-does-angularjs-bootstrap-datepicker-pick-one-day-before)

[Angular-UI One day is subtracted from date in ui-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226766/angular-ui-one-day-is-subtracted-from-date-in-ui-date)

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2628

But none of above solves the issue. Anyone have any solution?

Here is my Code:

```
scpApp.controller('InitiativeDetailCtrl', function ($scope, $element, $initiatives, $stateParams, $timeout, $location) {

$scope.datepickerOptions = {
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    language: 'en',
    startDate: "2000-10-01",
    endDate: "2030-10-31",
    autoclose: true,
    weekStart: 1
}

<input type="text" ng-option="datepickerOptions" ng-datepicker ng-model="initiative.end_date">
```

If I remove ng-option tag from input control. It selects correct date but then calendar does not close after date selection.

Please do not mark as duplicate. I have read all the previous questions but they are not able to solve the issue.

Comment: Could you provide a plunkr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using bootstrap datepicker

Include these links in index.html

```
 <link href="http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Html:

```
<input id="date-picker-1" type="text" class="date-picker form-control" name="dol" ng-model="emp.DOL" ng-init="emp.DOL = ''" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" />
<label for="date-picker-1" class="input-group-addon btn">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</label>
```

Controller:

```
 $(".date-picker").datepicker();
```

Comment: Yes i faced the same problem initially and then tried this.It works:).

Comment: Hi JanviM this is showing correct date but problem is it is not saving date into database.

Answer (score 0):

This is a timezone issue.  A date without a time is often assumed to be midnight at the beginning of the day. If that is then converted to a later timezone (e.g. UTC -> EST) it looks like the evening of the day before.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4837#issuecomment-203284205

Answer (score 0):

I have solved values not solving issue by this: (Controller code)

```
 $(".date-picker").datepicker({
        format: "mm-dd-yyyy",
        autoclose: "true"
    });
    $(".date-picker").on("change", function () {
        $scope.initiative.start_date = $(".date-picker").val();
        alert("selected date is " + $scope.initiative.start_date);

    });
```

More Info: [how to bind Bootstrap-datepicker element with angularjs ng-model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316937/bootstrap-datepicker-not-binding-with-angularjs-ng-model)