# Date picker is giving -1 one day date in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I am using date picker in my code ant its working but when I am selecting date from the control , Its populating before one day date.

Below is my code written in the html file.

```
<input id="id" type="date" class="form-control" name="approvalDate" ng-model="formModel.approvalDate" required="required">
```

So, date is coming current in the date box but in JSON its coming as -1 day.

Example - If I selecting 05/06/2017 then its coming in json as  06/06/2017.

Comment: Post your complete code what you had done yet

Comment: It is a timezone issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226766/angular-ui-one-day-is-subtracted-from-date-in-ui-date.

Comment: You are probably retrieving date value as UTC which may be expressed with few hours left dependeing on the country you are.

Comment: How can I change according to me.

Comment: is there any example, can some please share the example.